# What does 「フーホり」mean?

Tags: words

I recently started learning Japanese before my friend suggested I try out this cool app that lets me meet people from Japan to talk to.

I get a lot of japanese messages and in some requests the first word I notice is 「フーホり」. I looked it up in my Japanese dictionary but nothing pops up. If anyone know, please tell me.

Thank you.

Comment: 「ワーホリ」じゃなくて「フーホリ」? Edit: http://ameblo.jp/moedas/entry-12026252763.html They say it's 夫婦でワーホリ...

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with encoding problems (like [this one](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29809/5010))? An anonymized screenshot might help.

Comment: I'm with naruto on this one. That word has no meaning to me nor does it turn up anything with a Google search or a dictionary run, so I'm thinking it's an encoding issue.

Comment: I think naruto's theory is attractive, but choco's one is more probable. Make it sure you weren't confused among those letters: http://www.michaelhaldane.com/Hiragana%20and%20Katakana%20Tips.htm

Comment: OP said this "word" was seen in *some requests* by random Japanese people. I can hardly believe there were many Japanese people who used ワーホリ to a Japanese beginner. We really need some screenshot.

Comment: There is no such word as フーホリ, at least in standard Japanese. No way!

Answer (score 4):

Probably ワーホリ which is short for ワーキング・ホリデー (working holiday) which is a type of visa that allows the person to be in the country and work for about 1 year.

As a bonus bit of trivia:
Usually you are only eligible for that kind of visa before you are 30 years old, so when someone who is 30 gets a working holiday visa because it is their last chance they call it ギリホリ which is short for ギリギリでワーホリのビザを取った (only just got a working holiday visa in the nick of time).

Some Japanese people who like the idea of living overseas spend their entire 20s going from country to country on working holiday visas. Usually England, Australia, New Zealand, Canada, America.

Comment: What would be the chances of someone typing HU or FU by mistake when s/he meant to type WA?

Comment: @l'électeur: Much lower than the chances of someone reading ワ as フ by mistake, I guess.